# Extract data from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have data like this form:

```
X=[]; 
X=[X,0.114]; 
X=[X,0.749]; 
X=[X,0.358]; 
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to extract the values in the lists in a single list, as:

```
X = [0.114, 0.749, 0.358,...]
```

I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Xtest.txt')
count = data['X']
```

Could you please help me pull the values?
And thank you.

Comment: How is `X=[X,0.114]; X=[X,0.749]; X=[X,0.358];` CSV format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about plain python?
Something like

```
X = []
with open('Xtest.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        try:
            X.append(float(line.split(',')[1].split(']')[0]))
        except Exception:
            continue
print(X)
```

Comment: It returns a blank list `[ ]`.
Actually I edited my question, I think that my data is not sorted as CSV file, it is just a .txt file where the data are in that form.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer kindly try Again. I replaced `X.append(int(line.split(',')[1].split(']')[0])) ` with `X.append(float(line.split(',')[1].split(']')[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

If 0.114, 0.749, 0.358,..are the values in column1 of the CSV file, the answer is as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Xtest.txt')
y = data[0].to_list()
print(y)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
Sorry, I edited my question, I think that my data is not sorted as CSV file, it is just a .txt file where the data are in that form.